# Importing variables from another file (importlib)?

Tags: python, module, python-importlib, import-libraries

I'm trying to import variables from another python files.

`a.py` - to be imported

```
text="Hello, world"
print("imported")
```

`b.py` - works, but I cannot have static name `a`

```
from a import *
print(text)
```

`c.py` - not work

```
import importlib

X = "a"

try:
    text = ""
    i = importlib.import_module(X)
    print(i)
    print(text)
except ImportError as err:
    print('Error:', err)

try:
    text = ""
    i = importlib.__import__(X , globals=True, locals=True, fromlist=[], level=0)
    print(i)
    print(text)
except ImportError as err:
    print('Error:', err)

try:
    text = ""
    i = importlib.__import__(X , globals=True, locals=True, fromlist=[text], level=0)
    print(i)
    print(text)
except ImportError as err:
    print('Error:', err)
```

ouptut is:

```
imported
<module 'a' from '/tmp/a.py'>

<module 'a' from '/tmp/a.py'>

<module 'a' from '/tmp/a.py'>
```

but `text` varible not working.

`d.py` - not work

```
X = "a"
from X import *
print(text)
```

Is possible to use `importlib` as `from MODULE import *`?

Comment: You should NOT be using a star import at all actually - star imports pollute your namespace, make your code impossible to maintain (you don't know which module a name has been imported from) and break in unexpected ways (when you define in a new name in the imported module that happens to shadow another previously imported name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star imports ("from xxx import *") are bad practice (and actively discouraged by pep08) and should only be used as a convenient shortcut in a Python shell for a quick inspection / experimentation / debugging.

So your `b.py` code should either import the `a` module and use qualified path ie:

```
 # b.py
 import a
 print(a.text)
```

or (at worst) explicitely import the desired name(s) from `a`:

```
# b.py
from a import text
print(text)
```

Note that this second solution won't work as expected fior mutable globals, since in that case `text` becomes a module-local name in `b` so if `a.text` is rebound (reassigned) somewhere else `b.text` will not be impacted. But mutable globals are evil anyway...

Now assuming you do the RightThing and opt for the first solution (module import + qualified path), the "translation" using `importlib` would be:

```
import importlib
module_name = "a"
module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
print(module.text)
```

FWIW, all your attempts at using `importlib.__import__()` are wrong - `globals` is supposed to be a `dict`, and `fromlist` shoud be a list of names (strings). But there are very few good reasons for using `importlib.__import__()` instead of `importlib.import_module` actually.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to import of a variable from a dir on the same level or below you can use "import_module" coming from you cwd of the project:

```
        from importlib import import_module
        mod = import_module(
            f"{cwd}.source.myfolder.myfile"
        )
        var = getattr(mod, "my_variable")
```